# Swift music player 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Index (0) out of bounds (0)'

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaquery

I am developing a music app in swift and I'm having an issue when attempting to play an album using UITableViewRowAction. The first album I play works fine but when a second album is played afterwards I get an exception:

> 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Index (0) out of bounds (0)'

on the line:

```
self.audioPlayer.nowPlayingItem = myCollectionToPlay.items[0]
```

I always want to play the swiped album from the first track. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

```
let albumQuery: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.albums()
let audioPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

let play = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Play") { action, indexPath in

let albumTitle = self.allMusicInfo[indexPath.section].albums[indexPath.row].albumTitle

self.albumQuery.addFilterPredicate(MPMediaPropertyPredicate(
                                value: albumTitle,
                                forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle,
                                comparisonType: MPMediaPredicateComparison.equalTo
                            ))

let myCollectionToPlay = MPMediaItemCollection(items: self.albumQuery.items!)

self.audioPlayer.setQueue(with: myCollectionToPlay)

self.audioPlayer.nowPlayingItem = myCollectionToPlay.items[0]

self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

self.audioPlayer.play()

}
```

Comment: The error clearly indicates that `myCollectionToPlay.items` is an empty array which would indicate that `self.albumQuery.items` contains no items. That in turn indicates the predicate isn't finding any matches.

Comment: Thanks very much - I needed to use removeFilterPredicate before the next album played otherwise it was trying to match 2 album titles simultaneously.